# WordPress Plugin Coding Problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to convert a plugin I wrote procedurally to be class based, and it's not working for some unknown reason.  So I wrote cut down my plugin code to be about as minimilistic as possible.  When it runs, it comes back with no content.

```
    <?PHP
/**
 * Plugin Name:   A1 Test 
 * Version:       1.0.0
 * Plugin URI:    
 * Description:   Test
 * Author:        
 * Author URI:     
 */
if ( ! class_exists("TestingDemo") )
{
    class TestingDemo
    {
        function TestingDemo_filter( $buffer )
        {
            $buffer = preg_replace_callback( '@\[testing\s*=\s*"(.*?)\s*"\]@si',
                array(&$this, "TestingDemo_replace"), $buffer );
        }
        function TestingDemo_replace( $matches )
        {
            $message = $matches[1];
            return "Testing Worked.....   {$message}";
        }
    }
}
if ( class_exists("TestingDemo") )
{
    $TestingDemos = new TestingDemo();
}
if ( isset($TestingDemos) )
{
    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$TestingDemos, 'TestingDemo_filter') );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a return value for your `TestingDemo_filter()` function.  A Wordpress filter function needs to take a string as input, and return the modified string.  Since you've set up `TestingDemo_filter()` as the actual filter function, it's going to need a return value.

**Edit**

I just tested your code, and it definitely works when you add a `return` statement to `TestingDemo_filter()`.

Comment: Duh!  I cannot blieve i forgot the return.. :(  I spent hours trying to figure out what I did wrong..  It's good to have a fresh pair of eyes look at it.  

Thanks..

Comment: Ha ha, no problem.  We've all been there  ;)